# Nginx - Redirecting to specific directory like https://example.com/example, not working

Tags: http, nginx, redirect, https

I'm trying to redirect `upload.example.com` to `myuploadserver.example.com/s/example`.

When tying `upload.example.com` in my browser I'm taken to the base domain `myuploadserver.example.com` and not the sub-directory I want.

Here is my nginx file:

```
server {
  listen 8080;

  server_name upload.example.com;

  access_log /data/logs/redirection_host-7.log standard;

  location / {
        return 301 $scheme://myuploadserver.example.com/s/example$request_uri;
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to redirect to the specified directory?

Comment: It looks fine. What does `curl -I http://upload.example.com/` return? Is the HTTP `Location` response header set to the correct value?

Comment: I removed $request_uri and it seemed to work. Why is that?

Comment: You can see the difference using `curl -I http://upload.example.com/`. One redirects to `/s/example/` and the other to `/s/example`.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. It seems like when the URL ends in / it redirects me to the base URL. And without the / I'm taken to the desired URL. I'm using an application called NginxProxyManager and when i update the configuration in the app it automatically adds $request_uri to the end in the configuration file. Is there a way to work around this?